# How to I move a face so that the rest of the objects faces move proportionally

Tags: faces, proportional-editing

I'm very much a noob at blender so please forgive me if this is a simple question.

I want to create a loop de loop object and I think I'm almost there. How would I move the face at each end to the the rest of the object moves proportionally. I tried moving them using the proportional editing tool but only moves the first few segments.

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: use the mousewheel to change the radius of influence of the proportional editing

Comment: Thanks @wilks this sorted it perfectly. Told you I was a noob.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the title of the question but rather its body.

If you are going to use modifiers, you can consider using the screw modifier :

Create a single vertex a 1,0,0.

[image]

Add a screw modifier and tweak the screw offset property

[image]

add a skin modifier

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will also consider this in the future :)